# Is it possible to bind a Chrome extension keyboard shortcut to combinations that include Tab?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I have an extension shortcut bound to Ctrl-Tab in Chrome, as pictured here [image: The desired setting] but it does not seem to be possible to replicate this in the current version of Chrome on a new machine, as pressing Tab advances focus to the next field.

I've tried chrome sync, it syncs the extension but not the shortcut. I tried looking for it in my profile, but the config is stored in LevelDB files that are significantly more work to read than I'm willing to put in.

Is there any other way to do this?